File upload doesn't work as supposed in livewire 3
I have strange problem with simple upload function, I've just installed fresh Laravel 11 project with latest version of livewire just to test this out, when I select file to upload I see request update to serve and temp file stored in livewire-tmp folder which is fine but when I press upload I face console error file is undefined I attached picture for the error with example repo just to see my problem live:
https://github.com/hawkiq/livewire3-example

my UploadFile component
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Upload;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\Rule;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class UploadFile extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;


    public $file;

    public function mount()
    {
        // Debug the initial state
        logger('Component mounted with:', ['uploadedFile' => $this->file]);
    }

    public function updatedFile()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'file' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        dd('Upload');
       //Logic to upload file and save information to database
        session()->flash('message', 'File uploaded successfully.');
        $this->file = null;
        $this->dispatch('update-list');
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.upload-file');
    }
}


my view
<div class="card mt-2">
    <div class="card-header" style="background-color: cornflowerblue;color:white">
        Upload File
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form wire:submit='upload'>
            @csrf
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Select File</label>
                <input wire:model="file" name="file" id="file" type="file" class="form-control">
                @error('file')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Upload</button>
            </div>
            @if (session()->has('message'))
                <div class="alert alert-success mt-3">
                    {{ session('message') }}
                </div>
            @endif
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



I know this might be stupid but after I read whole livewire documents for upload file I realized am using reserved word "upload" in my component, I replaced it with "save" now everything works fine.
